# can`t add event listener to object. fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

can't add event listener to object. Maybe anybody had solved the same problem? I getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: canvas.on is not a function". I also use jQuery, can be problem in this? My code :

```
window.onload = function() {
       var canvas = new fabric.Element('canvas');
       var imgElement = document.getElementById('uploaded_img');
       var width = imgWidth = imgElement.width;
       var height = imgHeight = imgElement.height;

       if(width >= screen.width){
           width = (screen.width - 70);
       }

       canvas.setWidth(width);
       canvas.setHeight(height);

       var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
         left: width/2,            
         top: height/2         
       });                     
       canvas.add(imgInstance);

       canvas.on('mouse:up',function () {
          alert('test');
       });
}
```

Comment: I've never used canvas but your first line of code looks out of date. Instead of 'var canvas = new fabric.Element('canvas');' the current site initialisation code is all in the form:  'var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');'

Comment: I have tried both of this variant, but it doesn't work...

Comment: when I changed "canvas.on('mouse:up',function ()..." on "canvas.observe('mouse:up',function () " everything worked correct, but in docs recommended  use the first variant and as I know observe it is standard js function. Can anybody explain differences between canvas.on() an canvas.observe() in fabricjs, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html

```
fabric. Canvas
fabric.Element
new Canvas() §
Deprecated:
Use fabric.Canvas instead.
Source:
fabric.js, line 9066
```

So Fabric.Element is deprecated. Therefore it is highly advised not to use it.

Anyway, I cannot find anything in the docs about the methods of this deprecated 'Element'.

So I presume that the answer to your problem is to use the recommended Canvas constructor. I also presume that the on() method doesn't actually exist on Element, as the error says.